# Some time my groovy unable to set Soapui Project property though I have written the proper code

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am facing some problem with groovy code and `SoapUI`.  `Groovy` code works fine some times and some times not.

**Example:**  I have written a piece of groovy script which use to set project property of SoapUI and another piece of groovy Script to enable the TestSuite and TestCase if it is disabled.

But the problem here, it is working very inconsistently .

```
//To set Project Property
//Get Project
def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

//Set Project IP Property in Project level
def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' )
getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", "$IP")

//To enable TestSuite if its disable
 //get Project
def getProject = context.testCase.testSuite.project
 //get Test Suite Name
def TestSuite_Name = context.expand( '${DataSource#TestSuite_Name}' )
log.info TestSuite_Name

//Enable the TestSuite
getProject.getTestStepByName(TestSuite_Name).setDisabled(false)
```

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistently? Exceptions?

Comment: No there is Exceptions but //Set Project IP Property in Project level
def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' )
getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", "$IP") Actually when I am running this piece  of code it should set the Key and it's as a project level Property but It only able to set the key but unable to set the value for that .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is working sometimes but it is not working sometimes because of the missing "#" infront of soapUI variable

```
def IP = context.expand( '${#Properties#IP}' )
```

The following line is OK. No need to add "#" here

```
def TestSuite_Name = context.expand( '${DataSource#TestSuite_Name}' )
```

Refer to the SoapUI [Scripting Page](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html) for more syntaxes

Comment: Hi , You are correct but I am able to fetch the value some how but unable to set that key and value in project level property . That was my main qus . Now I modify that code as ${#Project#PropertyName} so same I am able to fetch the value but unable to set same in Project level property though I am using the code def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project //Set Project IP Property in Project level def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' ) getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", "$IP")

Answer (score 0):

Looks you got confused with the usages and it is the right expected behaviour from `SoapUI`.

`#` **should be prefixed** in the property expansion when you are referring a Test Case, Test Suite or Project level property.

Like in your case, `${#Project#PropertyName}`

`#` **is not required to prefix** in the property expansion when you are referring to a `Test Step Name`.

As you pointed in the other usage, `DataSource` is a test step name, not a property at any level, so `#` not needed.

Hence, `${DataSource#Whatever}`

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Hi , You are correct but I am able to fetch the value some how but unable to set that key and value in project level property . That was my main qus .  Now I modify that code as ${#Project#PropertyName} so same I am able to fetch the value but unable to set same in Project level property though I am using the code  def getProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

//Set Project IP Property in Project level
def IP = context.expand( '${Properties#IP}' )
getProject.setPropertyValue( "Project_IP", "$IP")

Comment: Either you clarify the question by editing or create a separate question as this is something different.